# Adding column to pandas python dataframe after groupby, maintaining order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with info like:

```
month     year        date       well_number  depth_to_water  
April     2007        4/1/07           1           48.60   
August    2007        8/1/07           2           80.20   
December  2007       12/1/07           EM3           37.50   
February  2007        2/1/07           27           32.00   
February  2008        2/1/08           27           40.00
```

I'm trying to create a new column with the year-to-year differences in each month's depth to water, so for 27: 32-40= -8

I've grouped the data frame, i.e.

```
grouped_dw = davis_wells.groupby(['well_number', 'month','year'], sort=True)
```

Which gives me exactly the sorting I need to theoretically just iterate through

```
well_number   month     year            date          depth_to_water          
1             April     2007           4/1/07           48.60   
                        2008           4/1/08           62.30   
                        2009           4/1/09           55.90   
                        2010           4/1/10           36.20   
                        2011           4/1/11           33.90
```

Out of which I'm trying to get:

```
well_number   month     year            date          depth_to_water   change       
1             April     2007           4/1/07           50               NaN
                        2008           4/1/08           60               -10
                        2009           4/1/09           55               5
                        2010           4/1/10           70               -15
                        2011           4/1/11           30               40
```

So I tried

```
grouped_dw['change'] = grouped_dw.depth_to_water(-1) - grouped_dw.depth_to_water
```

Which throws an error. Any ideas? Pretty sure I'm just not understanding how hierarchical groupedby Dataframes work.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I used sort, which gives me almost everything I need.. except I need it to give a null value when skipping to the next month.

```
davis_wells = davis_wells.sort(['well_number', 'month'])
davis_wells['change'] = davis_wells.depth_to_water.shift(1) - davis_wells.depth_to_water
```